# Batch rename MODIS data?

Tags: r, modis, batch, date, string

I have MOD13Q1 NDVI images. Data are named in this format:

```
MOD13Q1.A2007049.h26v06.006.2015161224938_MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI.tif
```

(YYYYDDD) Here 2007 is a year and 049 is day in year.

I have to rename it in this format: `(YYYY.MM.DD) 2007.02.18`

I am renaming it manually for every single file. How to perform a batch process for renaming all the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the following files:

```
MOD13Q1.A2007049.h26v06.006.2015161224938_MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI.tif
MOD13Q1.A2007051.h26v06.006.2015161224938_MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI.tif
```

and that they are stored in directory `C:/modis_files`

Run:

```
setwd('C:\\modis_files') #path to folder where MODIS files are.

file.rename(list.files(), paste(as.Date(substr(list.files(),10,16),"%Y%j"),".tif", sep=""))
```

It will result in:

```
2007-02-18.tif
2007-02-20.tif
```

---

If you want to keep the entire file name, while only replacing the [year + julian days], then [Bharadwaj A K's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307324/batch-renaming-modis-data/307326#307326) is the one.

Comment: Nice use of the `-` for the renamed file. Often Windows machines do not handle `.` characters when used other than the file extension.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use R language (open source), this will work.

```
setwd("C:/modis") #path of modis files
li<-as.data.frame(list.files(pattern = ".tif|.TIF"))
li$nn<-paste0(substr(li[,1],1,9),format(as.Date(substr(li[,1],10,16), "%Y%j"),"%Y.%m.%d"),substr(li[,1],17,75))
for(i in 1:nrow(li)){
  file.rename(as.character(li[i,1]),li[i,2])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that wants a Python approach, try the following:

```
import datetime, os, glob

inws = '/path/to/tiff/workspace'

tiffs = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))

for tiff in tiffs:
    julien_date = os.path.basename(tiff)[11:16] # Extract the julien date string
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(julien_date, '%y%j').date() # Format date
    outname = os.path.join(inws, date.strftime('%y-%m-%d') + ".tif") # Create outfile name and path
    os.rename(tiff, outname) # Rename the files
```